# Exception error while importing csv file (null values) to cassandra

Tags: csv, cassandra, cqlsh

I am trying to import csv file to Cassandra. My table is

```
copy info_by_vinid_search (vin_id,vinnumber,vin_start_date,vin_stop_date,cartype,bi_symbol,mercury_liability_symbol,pip_symbol,driving_wheels,cylinders,brakes,antitheft_code,daytime_lamps_ind, restraint,vsr_symbol_id,base_list_price,bodystyle_id,model_id,make_id,make_symbol,model_symbol,style_symbol,aux_symbol,polk_make,polk_model,polk_bodystyle,polk_engine_info_turbocharged,comp_symbol,coll_symbol,mb_symbol,ev_indicator,year,make,ncic_code,model,bodystyle,symbol_twodigit)FROM '36_vinid.csv' WITH DELIMITER = ',' AND HEADER=TRUE;
```

When I run the above copy command, it throws the below exception:

```
Process Process-21:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./cqlsh", line 1703, in multiproc_import
    cqltypes = [table_meta.columns[name].typestring for name in columns]
KeyError: 'antitheft_code'
```

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE vin_service_development.info_by_vinid_search (
    vin_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    aux_symbol text,
    base_list_price text,
    bi_symbol text,
    bodystyle text,
    bodystyle_id int,
    brakes text,
    coll_symbol text,
    comp_symbol text,
    cylinders text,
    driving_wheels text,
    ev_indicator text,
    make text,
    make_id int,
    make_symbol text,
    mb_symbol text,
    antitheft_code int,
    cartype text,
    daytime_lamps_ind text,
    liability_symbol text,
    model text,
    model_id int,
    model_symbol text,
    ncic_code text,
    pip_symbol text,
    polk_bodystyle text,
    polk_engine_info_turbocharged text,
    polk_make text,
    polk_model text,
    restraint text,
    style_symbol text,
    symbol_twodigit text,
    vin_start_date timestamp,
    vin_stop_date timestamp,
    vinnumber text,
    vsr_symbol_id int,
    year int
)
```

The sample data of csv file is

```
36_vinid.csv  
VIN_ID  VINNUMBER   VIN_START_DATE  VIN_STOP_DATE   CARTYPE BI_SYMBOL   LIABILITY_SYMBOL    PIP_SYMBOL  DRIVING_WHEELS  CYLINDERS   BRAKES  ANTITHEFT_CODE  DAYTIME_LAMPS_IND   RESTRAINT   VSR_SYMBOL_ID   BASE_LIST_PRICE BODYSTYLE_ID    MODEL_ID    MAKE_ID MAKE_SYMBOL MODEL_SYMBOL    STYLE_SYMBOL    AUX_SYMBOL  POLK_MAKE   POLK_MODEL  POLK_BODYSTYLE  POLK_ENGINE_INFO_TURBOCHARGED   COMP_SYMBOL COLL_SYMBOL MB_SYMBOL   EV_INDICATOR    YEAR    MAKE    NCIC_CODE   MODEL   BODYSTYLE   SYMBOL_TWODIGIT
    10591781,B5A5F5A----------             ,1997-10-01 00:00,9999-12-31 00:00,DM,,,,42,(null),,, ,,543,(null),12801,121020,7925,(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null), ,(null),(null),X,N,1975,AMERICAN,AMER,GREMLIN,SED 2DR,4
    10591361,B5A465E----------             ,1997-10-01 00:00,9999-12-31 00:00,DM,,,,42,(null),,, ,,543,(null),12801,121020,7925,(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null), ,(null),(null),X,N,1975,AMERICAN,AMER,GREMLIN,SED 2DR,4
    10591508,B5H465H----------             ,1997-10-01 00:00,9999-12-31 00:00,DM,,,,42,(null),,, ,,543,(null),12801,121020,7925,(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null), ,(null),(null),X,N,1975,AMERICAN,AMER,GREMLIN,SED 2DR,4
    10591548,B5A017A----------             ,1997-10-01 00:00,9999-12-31 00:00,DM,,,,42,(null),,, ,,543,(null),12669,121093,7925,(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null), ,(null),(null),X,N,1975,AMERICAN,AMER,HORNET,HCHBK 2DR,4
    10591869,B5F037E----------             ,1997-10-01 00:00,9999-12-31 00:00,DM,,,,42,(null),,, ,,543,(null),12669,121093,7925,(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null), ,(null),(null),X,N,1975,AMERICAN,AMER,HORNET,HCHBK 2DR,4
    10597770,B5A037H----------             ,1997-10-01 00:00,9999-12-31 00:00,DM,,,,42,(null),,, ,,544,(null),12669,121093,7925,(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null), ,(null),(null),X,N,1975,AMERICAN,AMER,HORNET,HCHBK 2DR,5
    10598750,B5A027A----------             ,1997-10-01 00:00,9999-12-31 00:00,DM,,,,42,(null),,, ,,543,(null),12801,121093,7925,(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null), ,(null),(null),X,N,1975,AMERICAN,AMER,HORNET,SED 2DR,4
    10592751,B5A037E----------             ,1997-10-01 00:00,9999-12-31 00:00,DM,,,,42,(null),,, ,,543,(null),12801,121093,7925,(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null), ,(null),(null),X,N,1975,AMERICAN,AMER,HORNET,SED 2DR,4
    10599752,B5A057H----------             ,1997-10-01 00:00,9999-12-31 00:00,DM,,,,42,(null),,, ,,543,(null),12801,121093,7925,(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null), ,(null),(null),X,N,1975,AMERICAN,AMER,HORNET,SED 2DR,4
```

I did import many csv files not having null values. I was able to import the data to Cassandra. Does the exception occur because of null values present in the csv file. Am I missing anything here? Please help.

Thanks..!!

Comment: Yes.. you are correct. I did miss that while copying and updated now.

Comment: @Aaron, there was some mismatch with the table schema and the attributes in the copy command. This was causing the exception. I did fix it and am able to load the data. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Excellent!  Converting my comments to an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your table definition?

Also, your file looks comma delimited, but your header appears to be tab-delimited. And you need to tell COPY that your header exists (`WITH HEADER=true`).